# Multiple solutions for a monic degree-5 polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$ for which all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ are roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

A monic degree-5 polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$ for which all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ are roots I found is $(x^5 - x)$ since

$f(1) \equiv$ 0(mod 5)
$f(2) \equiv$ 0(mod 5)
$f(3) \equiv$ 0(mod 5)
$f(4) \equiv$ 0(mod 5)
$f(5) \equiv$ 0(mod 5).

I am wondering, however, if there could be more than one answer. I noticed that $(x^5 - x)$ is a difference and can be factored but I don't know if that is a good conjecture.

Comment: $(x)(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)=x(x^2-1)(x^2-4)\equiv x(x^2-1)(x^2+1)=x(x^4-1)=x^5-x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I agree, but isn't this the same solution as $(x^5 - x)$?

Comment: yes, I think it's the only solution, because any solution has to be a multiple of $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)\equiv x^5-x$, and there's only one monic $5^{th}$ degree polynomial that fits that bill

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if their were two then their difference is a nonzero polynomial of degree $< 5$ with $5$ roots, contra: a polynomial in a field (or domain) [has no more roots than its degree.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242)

**Remark** $ $ More generally, by above if $f(x) = 0\,$ for all $x$ then $\deg f \ge 5.\,$ Let $\, g = x^5-x.\,$ Note $h = f\bmod g = f - q\,g\,$ also has $\,h(x) = 0$ for all $x$ and $\,\deg h < 5\,$ so $\, h = 0,\, $ so $\,f = q\,g.\,$ Thus any other polynomial having the same set of roots is a multiple of the minimal degree polynomial $g$.

**Remark** $ $ This is a special case of [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1841409/242) that ideals in Euclidean domains are principal - generated by any element of minimal Euclidean value(= degree here).